# have perl6 invoke the right multi sub specialized by subtype(subset)

Tags: raku, subtype, multidispatch

I have a type hierarchy constructed with perl6's subset command and some multi subs specialized on these type. How to give the highest precedence to the sub specialized by the most narrow subtype when multi dispatch happens?

Here is the simplified code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

proto check($value) { * }

subset Positive of Int where * > 0;

subset PositiveEven of Positive where * %% 2;

multi check(Int $value) {
    say "integer"
}

multi check(Positive $value) {
    say "positive"
}

multi check(PositiveEven $value) {
    say "positive & even"
}

# example:
check(32);

# expected output:
#   positive & even

# actual output:
#   positive
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since all candidates are equally tight, it will take the first one that matches the rest of the constraint (or lack thereof).  This is when the **order** in which the multi candidates are specified, becomes important.  If you would have specified them in this order:

```
multi check(PositiveEven $value) { say "positive & even" }
multi check(Positive $value) { say "positive" }
multi check(Int $value) { say "integer" }
```

The following *will* do what you expect:

```
check(32);   # positive & even
```

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is that Subsets are not actually types, just constraints.
If you do

```
say :(PositiveEven $value).perl;
say :(Positive $value).perl;
say :(Int $value).perl;
```

You will obtain

```
:(Int $value where { ... })
:(Int $value where { ... })
:(Int $value)
```

While the latest one is clearly different, the two others have no difference regarding signature, and thus the first one found is used. You will need either to declare them as classes or find another way to differentiate them by signature, or inside the sub itself using [nextsame](https://docs.raku.org/routine/nextsame)

```
proto check($value) { * }

subset PositiveEven of UInt where * %% 2;

multi check(Int $value) {
    say "integer"
}

multi check(UInt $value) {
    if $value ~~ PositiveEven {
    nextsame;
    }
    say "positive"
}

multi check(PositiveEven $value) {
    say "positive & even"
}
```

This will return `positive & even` as expected. You don't even need to define the last sub's arg as `PositiveEven`, but it's OK to leave it there for informative purposes.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. However the sub for Postive has to know the subtype derived from itself, which causes the code not extensible. Class and inheritance do the job too, but for some reasons I can't use them. Is it possible to make it run as well as be extensible without class?

Comment: @lovetomato you might try roles; you can use them in signatures too. I can't think of anything else off the top of my head... Maybe use parametrized roles instead of subsets... But I would have to check that...